# Finite simple nonabelian groups with the same character table

Tags: representation-theory

**Conjecture**: If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite simple nonabelian groups, and if $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same character table, then $G_1\cong G_2$.

I am looking for a proof, or at least some intuition. Or a counterexample? But finding a counterexample is certainly an exhaustive process.

Comment: It runs in my mind that $D_8$ and $Q$ have the same character table, yet are not isomorphic. But, these are not simple of course......

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57375/character-tables-and-simple-groups discusses this question.

Comment: The conjecture fails of course when we remove the simplicity condition.